# JQuery DatePicker calendar does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

On click in my input calendar don't appear.... this is my code js...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
     $("#dp1").datepicker();
   });
 </script>
```

and this is my html

```
<input type="text" id="dp1">
```

i thing i've imported wrong files... any suggest? ty

Comment: you haven't included main jquery.js file.

Comment: where i can found it?

Comment: here - http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jquery ,jquery ui only work with jquery

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $("#dp1").datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/467gm6Lg/)**