# Display only month and year not working with jQuery-2.1.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

My datepicker was working perfectly with jQuery-1.9.1.

HTML:

```
<label> Select month & year: </label>
<input name="month" class="month_year" placeholder="mm/yyyy"/>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
        $('.month_year').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        }).focus(function () {
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        });
    });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiWorld/1r7jp9uL/) is the jsfiddle of that.

But then we had to start using jQuery-2.1.1 and now my datepicker is not working. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

**Update**
Thank you "Pekka" for the reference. But even after adding the jqueryui files...this is what I am getting:

[image]

Whereas I am looking for the following format

[image]

Any suggestion? Thank you again!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784944/jquery-datepicker-calendar-does-not-appear check it

Comment: In fiddle you are still using `jquery-1.9`?

Comment: you are looking for `bootstrap datepicker`?

Comment: yes, i was try to show how my old one was working. But if i change it to `jquery-2.1.0` then it doesn't work

Comment: so you want only month and year format and do not want to display calendar?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, YES! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go,

```
$('.month_year').datepicker({
    format: 'MM yy',
    viewMode: "months", //this
    minViewMode: "months",//and this
    //autoClose:true
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1r7jp9uL/1/)**

You can also use `startView` instad of `viewmode` and set the option..

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)